# Apollo client fetchMore not updating data cache [Nextjs]?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am try to use `@apollo/client` in my `nextjs` application (only frontend). My backend is done using `nestjs-graphql`. I am facing one problem using `@apollo/client`.

Here is my code-

`client.ts`

```
//Initialize apolloClient
let apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;

//Creating link
function createIsomorphLink() {
    return new HttpLink({
        uri: "http://localhost:5000/piechat",
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
}

//Create apollo client
function createApolloClient() {
    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: true,
        link: createIsomorphLink(),
        cache: new InMemoryCache()
    })
}

//Initialize Apollo
export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
    const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()
    if (initialState) {
        const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract()
        const data = merge(initialState, existingCache)
        _apolloClient.cache.restore(data)
    }
    if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient
    return _apolloClient
}

//Use Apollo
export function useApollo(initialState = null) {
    const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState])
    return store
}
```

Then in nextjs `getServerSideProps`-

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo()
  await apolloClient.query({
    query: GET_CONVERSATION_LIST,
    context: { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ctx.req.cookies["session"]}` } },
    errorPolicy: "all"
  })
  return {
    props: {
      initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
    }
  }
}
```

Then in one `conversation.tsx`(I use this data)-

```
const { data } = useQuery<GetConversationData>(GET_CONVERSATION_LIST);
```

On the other component (`createConver.tsx`) I use `fetchMore` function-

```
const { fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_CONVERSATION_LIST)

useEffect(() => {
    if (data) { //If new data creation is success
        fetchMore({
            context: { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${getCookie("session")}` } }, updateQuery(_, { fetchMoreResult }) {
                return fetchMoreResult
            }
        })
    }
}, [data])
```

Everything is well. But when I refresh my page, I see that new data not comes. please see this gif- enter image description here

[image]

But I am not understanding what is the problem. I am not getting any docs or any things else. Please help me anyone.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040331/apollo-client-fetchmore-not-updating-data-cache from a sock-puppet account

Comment: Yes, I have 10 accounts.

Comment: Can you delete this copy of your question? Then I can look at the original.